# Vertically aligning h1 and keeping width at 100%

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="section-cover dark-cyan" ng-style="{height: getCoverHeight()}">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="intro">Some intro text.</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="arrow-holder" ng-click="scrollTo('video-container');">
        <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.section-cover` div changes height dynamically based on viewport size whenever the browser is resized. I need to align the `<h1>` element vertically inside the `section-cover` div. So far I've achieved that using `display: table-cell` however now I can't get the width to stick at `100%`. Here's a JSFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/AvrrM/

How can I modify this to vertically align the `<h1>` and keep the width at 100%?

Comment: `line-height: 200px;` on your `.section-cover` ? http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/AvrrM/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why is itsn't working??** because `table-cell` is similar to html table, you need to provide a container which is `table` type before you can make the `table-cell` occupy the full width!!

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AvrrM/4/)

add this CSS in your markup :

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#table {
    width: 100%;
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="table">
<div class="section-cover dark-cyan" style="background: blue; color: white; height: 200px">

<!-- all inner html here -->

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/AvrrM/1/

```
.section-cover {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

.container{
    display: table-cell;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```